# Why would I need a relay between a DC motor and my Arduino?

Tags: relay, dc-motor

I was told that I should put a relay between my 5V motor and my Arduino. I asked why, but they didn’t know.

Why do I need to separate them with a relay? The motor requires 5V and the Arduino provides 5V.

Also, do I need to separate all components from the motor with a relay or could I, for example, put them in the order:

```
Arduino -> Relay -> Demultiplexer -> Motors?
```

Comment: It is about the current. Relay is too much of a hassle here, transistor is enough.

Comment: Please, tell us what you are actually trying to do, show us pictures, what is the motor being used for? Where does your "someone" tell you to put the relay - between the 5V supply and the motor? Please tell me you are not powering a motor from the 5V regulator on your arduino.

Comment: Please tell me you are not powering a motor *direct from an IO pin on the Arduino...!*

Comment: @Majenko im not doing any thing yet, im asking before i do something stupid, but yes that was my first idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One Arduino OUTPUT pin should be used to supply no more than 0.02A (20mA) current. (one pin has an absolute maximum safe current of 40mA, however, that is reduced if other pins on the same 8pin port is being used as an output).

Most electric motors need *much* more current than an Arduino pin can supply. A small, low-cost, electric motor, the sort of thing used in toys, might require 0.5A current.

A motor uses the most current when it is starting up, or something holds the motor shaft strongly enough to stop it (stall). So check both the voltage and current rating for running and the stall current of a motor.

A relay may allow an Arduino pin to supply a small amount of current, yet control a much larger current for the motor. A relay may be activated by the Arduino pin, and it's contacts might be capable of supplying the motor's needs. It is *not* automatically true that an Arduino can drive a relay. A reay might also use more current than an Arduino pin can safely supply. So a relay specification has to be checked too. It should not require more than 40mA absolute maximum, at 5V to operate.

There are other technologies which enable one Arduino pin to switch electrical loads which are much bigger than it can directly supply. For example things called solid-state relays, 'BJT' power transistors or power MOSFET transistors. There are also Integrated Circuits (ICs) designed to drive motors.

Edit (to incorporate Andreas Wallner's comment):
When power to motor is switched off, the motor will continue to spin for a short time. While it is spinning, it acts as an electricity generator. If the motor were connected directly to an Arduino pin, that power would try to go via the electronics of the pin, and would likely damage it. A motor connected to a relay will generate electricity when the relay opens. The voltage produced by the motor will rise quickly, and could even cause an 'arc', or spark. The motors generated voltage is usually conducted away to avoid this effect using a diode. (Search for this using the term 'freewheeling diode'). The diode will be connected in the *opposite* direction to the flow of current to the motor.

If the motor is being driven in *both* directions, then use four diodes two on each motor wire. Two diodes, one on each wire, will connect motor wires to ground. Two, one on each wire, will connect the motor wire to the positive power supply. All four diodes will connect so that no power would flow normally. They will conduct away any power produced by the motor, and prevent arcing on a relay, or power running back though electronics.

It is also worth noting that a DC electric motor works by making and breaking contact, through its 'brushes', continuously, while it spins. This can also generate arcing or sparks. This creates a *lot* of electrical noise, which can 'upset' electronics, like an Arduino. Electrical noise can cause electronics to operate unreliably. This noise is usually dramatically reduced by connecting a ceramic or polyester capacitor, about 1nF to 10nF, across the motors terminals.

You would normally supply a motor using a relay, and keep other components separate, for example a demultiplexer would not be part of the motors circuit.

Comment: Another problem would be the voltage when switching the motor off, since you have a turning motor on the coils in the motor. Even if the motor can be driven by the I/O pin one might want to add a freewheeling diode to the circuit...

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, a motor is a very power hungry device.  An Arduino IO pin can only provide an *absolute maximum* of 40mA from an IO pin, and Atmel don't guarantee anything over 20mA.  A motor typically takes considerably more than that, especially during it's acceleration phase.

Powering a motor direct from an IO pin is not only a Bad Idea™ but is also doomed to failure from the outset.

So you need something to provide more current to the motor, and that means some form of external switch.

Yes, you can use a relay as that switch, however a relay also suffers the same problems as a motor - they are generally quite power hungry, and need some form of external switch to allow the Arduino to drive them.  Yes, you can get relays that are weak enough for an Arduino to drive direct, and you can get relays with built in switching circuits, but in general most relays are too powerful for a mere Arduino to switch.

So you need another option, and that option is a transistor.

Secondly, motors (and relays) are very noisy devices.  Regardless of the amount of current required to drive them, they will be creating lots and lots of voltage spikes, both positive and negative, on their connections.  You really don't want those spikes going into your Arduino an making the Magic Smoke™ escape.  So you need to divert them elsewhere.  That requires a diode reverse biased across the winding / coil of the motor / relay.  Also the transistor you use to drive the motor or relay acts as an extra layer of separation from the Arduino keeping those spikes away.

So follow the (millions of examples - ask Google) standard circuits for driving a relay or motor through a transistor from an Arduino and you will be safe.